# Rails 3 - images not rendering correctly on first page view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

In my rails3 app I've got an image gallery where:

```
gallery has many images
image belongs to gallery
```

I'm using carrierwave to upload images to S3.

My gallery page ('show' action) displays thumbnails for each image in that gallery.

I use colorbox to display the images modally when a user clicks on the thumbnail.

Quite often, I see this after clicking on an image:

[image: good_image]

what I want to see is this:

[image: bad_image]

I've done a LOT of troubleshooting:

- Tried using FancyBox instead of ColorBox - same problem
- Tried using different branch of CarrierWave - same problem
- Tried putting my images in European Buckets (I'm in Europe) - same problem
- Tried eager loading my images along with the gallery - same problem
- Tried using Google Hosted jQuery 1.4.1, and 1.4.3 - same problem
- Uploaded everything to Heroku - same problem
- Tried explicitly setting the width of my colorbox (as well as various other content divs)
- Edited ACL for S3 Bucket
- Using html5 doctype for images.html.haml (layout for images controller)

This tends to **the first time I click on thumbnail** *after it has been uploaded* although I've noticed it happening with images I've not clicked on in over an hour or so too. The problem goes away if I click on the thumbnail again immediately after the failure.... I never have any trouble with the thumbnails, they all load fine. It seems as though the large (original) version of the image is not getting downloaded on the first attempt.

- There are no errors in my logs.
- This is driving me absolutely NUTS.
- I'm using Fog gem version 0.3.13.

What else can I do here?  What more troubleshooting can I try?  Any help would be appreciated.

Here's some of my code:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery
  mount_uploader :photo, ImageUploader
  attr_accessible :photo, :gallery_id
  validates_presence_of :photo
end

class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope order("id DESC")
  has_many :images
  attr_accessible :name, :images_attributes, :description
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  validates_presence_of :name
end

#images/show.html.haml
= image_tag @image.photo_url if @image.photo_url

#galleries/show.html.haml
- for image in gallery.images
  .image
    = link_to image_tag(image.photo_url(:thumb)), image_path(image), :name=>"modal", :class=>"group" if image.photo_url(:thumb)

#layouts/images.html.haml
!!! 5
%html
  %body
    #image
      = yield
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suspect your problem has to do with CSS and not the app itself. The first time the image loads the browser will not know the width or height of it, so it goes in at some arbitrary and usually wrong size. Subsequent requests will load the image from cache very quickly, possibly before the JavaScript has a chance to run, which means that the width and height attributes are populated correctly.

You might be able to fix this by putting the width and height attributes in the HTML that is sent to the client. Attachment systems like Paperclip allow you to extract and save this information, but do not do it by default.

Comment: your advice 'seems' to be right - I will monitor this for a few hours so that I can be certain - but it looks fixed. I just added some width and height attributes to my javascript and that looks to have sorted this out - thanks a lot, you really helped ;)